# Knockout Typescript viewmodel functions are not defined

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am running into an issue where I can't use functions I've declared in my models inside my view. To me, it seems like the functions do exist, so I'm not sure why the console tells me they don't exist.

I have extracted relevant parts of my view here:

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h3>Examens</h3>
    </div>
    <!-- ko foreach: examAttempts -->
    <div class="panel-header clickable" data-bind="click: () => toggleOpen()">
        <h3 class="d-block">
            Examen poging #<span data-bind="text: $index"></span>
            <span class="pull-right" data-bind="css: { fa: true, 'fa-chevron-left': !open(), 'fa-chevron-down': open() }"></span>
        </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body" data-bind="visible: open">
        <!-- ko foreach: questions -->
        <p>
            <b><span data-bind="text: formatQuestion($index)"></span></b>
            <br />
            <span data-bind="text: answer"></span>
            <br />
            <i>Beantwoord in: <span data-bind="text: time"></span> seconde(s)</i>
        </p>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
    <br /><br /><br />
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

These are my view models (ommitted irrelevant fields):

```
class ExamAttempt {
    questions: KnockoutObservableArray<ExamQuestion>;
    open: KnockoutObservable<boolean>;

    constructor(questions: any) {
        this.questions = ko.observableArray<ExamQuestion>(questions);
        this.open = ko.observable<boolean>(false);
    }

    public toggleOpen(): void {
        this.open(!this.open());
    }
}

class ExamQuestion {
    question: KnockoutObservable<string>;
    answer: KnockoutObservable<string>;
    time: KnockoutObservable<number>;

    constructor(question: string, answer: string, time: number) {
        this.question = ko.observable<string>(question);
        this.answer = ko.observable<string>(answer);
        this.time = ko.observable<number>(time);
    }

    public formatQuestion(index: number): string {
        return `${index + 1}. ${this.question()}`;
    }
}

class EditUserProfileModel {
    examAttempts: KnockoutObservableArray<ExamAttempt>;

    constructor(params: any) {
        this.examAttempts = ko.observableArray<ExamAttempt>(params.examAttempts);
    }
}
```

Applying bindings (`params` is the page model serialized):

```
ko.applyBindings(new EditUserProfileModel(params));
```

The errors I am getting (well, they just say the functions are undefined, but to me it seems like they shouldn't be):

[image]

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is `params.examAttempts`? Is it a collection of simple javascript objects or are they created using `new ExamAttempt()`?

Comment: did you try using lambda syntax for your function? Like this - public formatQuestion = (index: number): string => {
        return `${index + 1}. ${this.question()}`;
    }

Comment: Unrelated, but it should probably be `index()` in js or `$index()` in your HTML

Comment: I have created [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adigas/dcmuu8Ly/1/) with your code. Except for `$index()` there is no problem in your code. You have not mentioned what `params` looks like.

Comment: Yes I figured it out, it was a problem with types. Apparantly, even though `params.examAttempts` has the same structure and same fields as `ExamAttempt` class, js/ts does not turn it into an instance of `ExamAttempt`, which was the problem here (because the functions were defined in `ExamAttempt` class). My bad!. Thanks for taking the time to create a fiddle.

Comment: As mentioned in the fiddle, you need to create `new ExamQuestion()` and `new ExamAttempt()`. Otherwise, those objects won't have `toggleOpen` in their `prototype`.

Comment: Yes that is what I ended up doing. Thanks for your time/help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I figured it out, it was a problem with types. Apparantly, even though `params.examAttempts` has the same structure and same fields as `ExamAttempt` class, js/ts does not turn it into an instance of `ExamAttempt`, which was the problem here (because the functions were defined in `ExamAttempt` class). My bad!.

@adiga, thank you for taking the time to create a fiddle.

To fix it, I changed this line:

```
this.examAttempts = ko.observableArray<ExamAttempt>(params.examAttempts)
```

Into:

```
this.examAttempts = ko.observableArray<ExamAttempt>(params.examAttempts.map((ea: any) => {
    let questions = ea.questions.map((eaq: any) => {
        return new ExamQuestion(eaq.question, eaq.answer, eaq.time);
    });

    return new ExamAttempt(questions);
}));
```